# F# matching with empty list when list given is not empty

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find the transpose of a matrix, I know my code so far is not correct but what I'm more concerned about is why when I test it with
transpose `[[4;3];[1;5];[6;7]]` it's going to the first match case which is an empty list?

```
let rec transpose = function
     | [] -> failwith "Error, no matrix supplied"
     | [[]] -> []
     | [[x]] -> [[x]]
     | x::xs -> let temp = List.head x :: (List.map (fun n -> List.headn) xs)    
                temp :: transpose(xs);;
```

Comment: It's not doing that directly, it's via the recursive call at the end of the last case.

Comment: surely it will go there once the `x::xs` case recursively reaches the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case 2:

```
[[]]
```

will match a list containing an empty list.

Case 3:

```
[[x]]
```

will match a list containing a list containing a single item.

This case:

```
x::xs
```

does some processing on `x` and then recurses on `xs`, so calling `transpose` on `[[4;3];[1;5];[6;7]]` will result in recursive calls to `transpose` with the following parameters:

```
[[4;3];[1;5];[6;7]]
[[1;5];[6;7]]
[[6;7]]
[]
```

You can see that none of these values matches Case 2 or Case 3 and the final values matches Case 1, so the recursion will eventually terminate on Case 1.

Comment: Thank you, this made me understand it so clearly now! One more question if I test it with transpose [], I'm getting a value restriction error...why is this happening?

Comment: "How to fix it" part is: using  `List.empty<int>` in place of `[]` should help. As to "why" part - try to grok [Finer Points of F# Value Restriction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) IMO one of the best explanations.

Answer (score 3):

One of the options of finding the transpose of a matrix:

```
let transpose (matrix: 'a list list) = 
    let rec loop x number count = 
        if number < count then
            loop (List.foldBack(fun x acc -> (List.nth x number)::acc) matrix []::x) (number + 1) count
        else x
    if matrix.IsEmpty then []
    else loop [] 0 matrix.Head.Length |> List.rev


[[4;3];[1;5];[6;7]] |> transpose |> printfn "%A"
[[4;3;2];[1;5;0];[6;7;9];[4;3;2];[1;5;0]] |> transpose |> printfn "%A"
[] |> transpose |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
[[4; 1; 6]; [3; 5; 7]]
[[4; 1; 6; 4; 1]; [3; 5; 7; 3; 5]; [2; 0; 9; 2; 0]]
[]
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/095DRq